# ¿Es correcto traducir «nothing but <x>» como «nada mas <x>»?

Tags: traducción

En uno de los [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) recientes, era necesario traducir la típica locución inglesa «*nothing but*», que normalmente se traduce como «nada excepto» o «nada salvo».

Sin embargo, [una de las respuestas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/revisions/21529/1) proponía traducirla como «nada mas», usando **mas** sin tilde en su significado de «pero»; es decir, una traducción literal que, no obstante, suena bastante bien.

¿Sería correcta esta traducción?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como aludido voy a responder yo también. Sí que es cierto que en su momento no me sonó mal, pero luego investigando un poco vi que *pero* y *mas* tienen una ligera diferencia en sus significados. Así, *[mas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OWE2P4C)* puede equivaler a *[sino](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XywVM1a%7CXywriSz)* en su cuarta acepción. Y la frase

> [No había] nada sino rocas...

es correcta. ¿El problema? Que en esa frase se usa la primera acepción de *sino*:

> U. para contraponer un concepto afirmativo a otro negativo anterior.

Un ejemplo de frase con *mas* usando esa cuarta acepción de *sino* ("denota adición de otro u otros miembros a la cláusula") sería:

> No solo lo hizo Juan, mas también Pedro.

En el CORDE tampoco he encontrado ningún ejemplo de *nada mas* con el significado propuesto. Así pues, resumiendo yo mismo acabé descartando la validez de la expresión.

Comment: @walen hombre, el ahorro tuvo que ver, pero sí que es verdad que ante tu duda ya me puse a investigar, y esto fue lo que encontré. En absoluto quería evitar la duda. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Como traducción literal "funciona", pero el significado se pierde totalmente. En español la expresión "nada pero X", que es completamente equivalente, no tiene ningún significado; en cambio, "nada excepto" o "nada salvo", como tú sugieres, mantienen el significado inglés. Así pues, yo no la daría por válida.

Comment: "nada mas" o "nada pero" son, a mi entender, incorrectos. A lo sumo, podría decirse: "nada sino". (Nota: En traducción, "equivalente" no significa "literal" sino todo lo contrario -- son "equivalentes" los términos o frases que tengan idéntico valor en ambos idiomas, de modo tal que la meta de cualquier traductor es encontrar "translation equivalents".)

Answer (score 2):

¡Cuidado! Ésta pregunta es mucho más interesante de lo que parece.

A primera vista estás simplemente traduciendo palabra por palabra y perdiendo el significado de una expresión. Pero *"mas"* tiene, entre otros, el significado que intentas aplicar...

- Es correcto decir "la caja no tiene nada más que basura". esto añade un "no" y un "que", haciendo la expresión más larga.
- Al menos en México, puedes decir "la caja tiene nada mas basura". El problema es que ésta construcción corresponde a "the box has **only** trash". No sé si la expresión original tenía este sentido.
- Si "nada mas" es aceptable, se puede considerar la contracción "nomás", y ésa estoy seguro solo se usa en México. De acuerdo a las reglas de translation-golf, esto requeriría revisar el resto de la traducción para asegurar que se usa el mismo dialecto en todas partes.

Comment: ‘nomás’ es una contracción que también se usa en el resto de Latinoamérica y arriesgaría  que hasta en España, revisá esa parte

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta simple a tu pregunta: Sí es correcto traducirlo así.

Sin embargo, este es el problema de querer traducir algo literalmente sin pensar en cómo se dicen las expresiones  normalmente en español.

Mira unos de los usos más comunes de **nothing but** en Inglés, y cómo lo podrías decir en Español:

- nothing but lies. **puras mentiras.**
- nothing but thieves. **ladronzuelos,** o **simples ladrones.**
- nothing but trouble. **no dan sino problemas.**
- nothing but the truth. **nada más que la verdad.**
- nothing but the blood (of Jesus) **sólo (de Jesús) la sangre**
- nothing but a good time **sólo pasarla bien** o **nada más que pasarla bien.**
- nothing but net. **limpia** (hablando de baloncesto).

O sea, hay muchas formas de decir algo apropiadamente en Inglés, y también en Español. Dilo de una forma expresiva según el contexto, no sólo palabra por palabra.